# C++ how to pass command line args between processes?

Tags: c++, command-line, process, pipe, args

I have a parent process that needs to send it is command line args to the its child? How I can do this? I mean from parent.cpp to child .cpp?
Thanks

Comment: by using an IPC mechanism

Comment: How are you creating the process?

Answer (score 2):

#POSIX (Linux) solution:

Use **[`execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[])`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp)** to run a programme with arguments in place of the current programme.  The `argv[]` that you pass as reference, follows the same logic as the `argv[]` parameter passing in `main()`.

If you want to keep your current process running and launch the new programme in a distinct process, then you have to first **[`fork()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)**.  The rough idea is something like:

```
pid_t pid = fork();  //  creates a second process, an exact copy of the current one
if (pid==0)  {  // this is exectued in the child process
    char **argv[3]{".\child","param1", NULL }; 
    if (execvp(argv[0], argv))   // execvp() returns only if lauch failed
         cout << "Couldn't run "<<argv[0]<<endl;   
}
else {  // this is executed in the parent process 
    if (pid==-1)   //oops ! This can hapen as well :-/
         cout << "Process launch failed";  
    else cout << "I launched process "<<pid<<endl; 
}
```

#Windows solution

The easiest windows alternative is to use the ms specific **[`_spawnvp()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20y988d2.aspx)** or similar functions.  It takes same arguments as the exec version, and the first parameters tells if you want to:

- replace the calling process (as exec in posix)
- create a new process and keep the calling one (as fork/exec combination above)
- or even if you want to suspend the calling process until the child process finished.

Answer (score 0):

If fork() is used, then the child process inherits from the parent process.

`http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html`

If you mean just passing variables between instances of objects in memory, then you'd create variables for `int argc` and `char * argv[]` to pass along.

Answer (score 0):

In parent. Use

```
system("child_application my arg list");
```

In child. Use

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

For easy parsing args try boost program_options library.

In unix system can use `fork`. Child process get all parent memory.

Comment: Good idea !  But `system()` runs a shell command which will run the child.  The shell might interpret process the arguments before they are passed to the child.  THis can have advantages and inconveniences.